# Docker Image expiration date

Tags: docker

I would like to distribute a docker container from a private registry, but I would like to enforce a use period (e.g. 30 days) from the time the container is pulled.  Is there a way to do this without complex license servers?

After 30 days, the expectation is they would be required to pull again or at least log into the registry.  Any time we remove someone's registry access, the container will be invalid at a max of 30 days later.

Comment: I am not aware of a feature/tool can do that... but maybe possible if you have a daily build image that has an entrypoint checks and refuse to startup 30 days after the build date.  Your private registry needs to provide a daily build image.